# Как разместить разные элементы на одной высоте

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть 3 кнопки с позицией  relative размещенные в ul li
Пример:

```
<ul>
  <li><button></button></li>
  <li><button></button></li>
  <li><button></button></li>
</ul>
```

Хочу разместить их с равной высотой однако один выходит ниже другого
Пытался top убавлять но выглядит это не очень

Добавлял width / height без результата [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Куча вариантов, display: flex,  display: grid,  display: inline-block

Comment: Скажите, они обязательно должны быть relative? Или вам нужна определенная разметка? Если это так - добавьте скриншот разметки с макета

Comment: Нет не обязательно (желательно) 
Проблема уже решена спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `display: inline`

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
 
}

li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><button>Кнопка 1</button></li>
  <li><button>Кнопка 2</button></li>
  <li><button>Кнопка 3</button></li>
</ul>
```